# Runtime error for Leetcode question: Two Sum

Tags: c++

Error:
Line 1034: Char 9: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'int' (stl_vector.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1043:9

My Code:

```
vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        vector<int> sol;
        int temp, i = 0, l = nums.size();
        while(true && i < l)
        {
            temp = nums[i] - target;
           int it = nums.end() - find(nums.begin(), nums.end(), temp);
            if(it == 0)
            {   i++;
                continue;
            }
            sol[0] = i;
            sol[1] = it;
            break;
        }
     return sol;   
    }
```

Comment: I suspect `find()` is not finding temp and is returning nums.end().  You need to check the return value before using it.

Comment: Also instead of `sol[0]` and `sol[1]` try `push_back()`

Answer (score 0):

The problem statement from [Two Sum - LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/) says:

> Given an array of integers `nums` and an integer `target`, return *indices of the two numbers such that they add up to `target`*.
>
> You may assume that each input would have ***exactly* one solution**, and you may not use the same element twice.
>
> You can return the answer in any order.

The bigger issue in the posted implementation is the repeated access out of bounds of `sol`, which is declared as an *empty* vector:

```
vector<int> sol;
```

Later, in loop, it's accessed via `operator[]` at indices 0 and 1, but those elements don't exist. So, to fix it, just declare a vector of *two* elements.

```
std::vector<int> sol(2);
```

---

Other minor issues (not really errors) are the followings:

```
int temp, i = 0, l = nums.size();
while ( true && i < l )
{ //    ^^^^^^^          Why? It's pointless.

    int it = nums.end() - find(nums.begin(), nums.end(), temp);
    //                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^   
    // This traverses the vector every time from the beginning, which is a waste.
    // Also, "you may not use the same element twice". 
    // Just start from the element after nums[i].

    if(it == 0)    // Consider to invert the logic: break when a pair is found
    { 
        i++;
        continue;
    }
    sol[0] = i;   // Already addressed, but...
    sol[1] = it;
    //       ^^  I lied, this IS another error. 
    //           Do you remember how 'it' was calculated?
    break;
}
```

To summarize, this is a possible solution

```
std::vector<int> twoSum(std::vector<int> const& nums, int target)
{ // We are not modifying it, so         ^^^^^
 
    std::vector<int> sol(2);
    // IMHO, a std::pair would have been a better fir, here.
    
    for (auto i{ nums.cbegin() }; i != nums.cend(); ++i)
    { // It's const...                     ^

        auto const j = std::find(i + 1, nums.cend(), *i - target);
        // Don't count twice     ^^^^^
      
        if( j != nums.cend() )
        { //  ^^   
            sol[0] = std::distance(nums.cbegin(), i);
            sol[1] = std::distance(nums.cbegin(), j);
            //       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^      Count from the beginning.
            break;
        }
    }
    return sol;   
}
```